# Strapi v4 + Postgres + heroku = Error “Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?”

Tags: strapi

I get this error when I run npm run develop command .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error might be misleading. It also throws this for me sometimes when the database (pool) is not available at all. Did you check it is? and the credentials are valid?